# Slack API and sending message containing a video

Tags: slack-api

is there any way how to send a message with video content to Slack over its API? I see support only for an image here https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/layouts

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is link to a video file in the body of the message, and then Slack will "unfurl" (preview) it alongside the message. There's no native video block today.

Comment: what about this https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#video ?

Answer (score 0):

You could upload the video to Slack as any other file, using the [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) method. If you also specify `channels` and `initial_comment` parameters, the file will be posted to respective channels with messages.

Alternatively, upload the file without posting to channels, grab the file ID from the response (like `F0TD00400`) and pass it as an `external_id` to the [File Block](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#file).